# Halting macro code execution until SQL query is completed

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have written a fairly complex application that uses Excel (2016) as front-end application for data stored in a MS Access database, using the ADO 6.1 library. I have noticed during macro code execution that SQL transactions triggered by my Excel application can take quite long to complete, and often the execution of the next line of code in my Excel macro depends on this SQL transaction first being completed. Unfortunately, macro code execution and SQL transactions are asynchronous operations, which means that the macro jumps to the next line of code even though the SQL transaction hasn't been completed.

My current work-around is to use a Sleep() function using the Windows API to insert a fixed delay, but this is a really ugly solution as it does reduce the performance of my application and depends very much on the CPU load, so it may sometimes work, sometimes not.

I haven't been able to find so far a solution to this problem, I can't find any hints on the Internet either.

Using Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone doesn't help here either.

Does anyone have an idea or a hint how to halt macro code execution in Excel until an SQL transaction has been completed? Is there a method in ADO to check the completion of an SQL transaction?

Comment: It is not awaited behavior to my mind, vba AFAIK does next operation after previous has been executed

Comment: show relevant code snippets

Answer (score 1):

Is your query within the Data/connections section?

I had this problem to, I turned off "Enable Background refresh" and added "DoEvents" to the VBA, this forces the data connection to refresh before it allows the code to continue. Downside to this is it makes excel feel like its locked up, But this resolved my issue.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("ScrapData").Refresh
DoEvents


....Other code....


End With
```